# How to change this raw statement to do the opposite

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have this raw SQL statement that takes a full name, no matter how many names, and makes it into
Last word in the string as the Last name
And everything else as the First name

```
DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 1) AS firstname");
DB::raw("TRIM(SUBSTRING(user_fullname, 1, LENGTH(user_fullname) + 
    CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 2)))) AS lastname");
```

I want it to do the opposite, by making it into the first word in the string as the First Name and everything else as the last name; I tried around with the code, but everything I do seems to break it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have a database with full names, alot of the times, the names consist of 3, 4 or 5 names together, I just want to split it into first name, where the first name is only the first word from the data, and everything else is last name. Hope this explains it better.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(user_fullname, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 1))+2) AS lastname` …?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use php for this?
Something like that:

```
$string = "first1 first2 first3 first4";
$pos = strrpos($string," ");
$firstname = substr($string,0,$pos);
$lastname = substr($string,$pos+1);
```

Comment: It works within php, but I would like to do it inside query builder instead. Thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked for me!

```
SUBSTRING(user_fullname, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 1))+2) AS lastname
```